# How to get location info from Facebook photo object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a question about Facebook Graph API.

Here are two FB photo objects with geo location, in the first photo, the geo location is "Rio Douro", and the geo location in the second photo is "Santa Clara, Portugal 附近".

I know I can use graph API like "{photo-id}?fields=place" to get the location info (Rio Douro) from the first photo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/drnMQ.jpg

But how can I get the location info from the second photo?
"{photo-id}?fields=place" won't return anything....:(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VWsP.jpg

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, that information is not part of the Photo's details but is general information attached to the post; it's not retrievable via the API

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your answer!! :D